# hashfile for files in define paths using BATCH

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am trying to get the MD5 values of all files in sub folders that are in external file PathList.txt.

I can't make the script use the path names as define in `%%i`.

In the example I used `"C:\Temp\example\"` in the place of `%%i` so the script will work.

```
@ECHO off
echo Files MD5 > MD5_log.txt

FOR /F %%i IN (PathList.txt) DO (
    @FOR /R "C:\Temp\example\" %%G in (*) DO (
     for  %%a in (%%G) do certutil -hashfile "%%~a" MD5 | find /i /v "certutil">> MD5_log.txt
     )
)
```

PathList.txt

```
C:\folder1\
C:\folder2\
```

This is for an old computer, I don't have Powershell option.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

#### I can't make the script use the path names as defined in `%%i`

Please find below a working batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Files MD5 > MD5_log.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (PathList.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=*" %%j in ('dir /b /s "%%i"') do (
    certutil -hashfile "%%j" MD5 | find /i /v "certutil" >> MD5_log.txt
    )
  )
endlocal
```

Sample output:

```
> type PathList.txt
f:\test\bar
f:\test\bar - Copy
f:\test\foo

> test
> type MD5_log.txt
Files MD5
MD5 hash of file f:\test\bar\test.cmd:
eb 4f 28 f4 a0 b0 c5 21 0d e8 5f 99 0f d8 fd ab
MD5 hash of file f:\test\bar\test.html:
3a 68 3a f6 4e 88 f1 22 62 d6 46 dc bb 54 59 45
MD5 hash of file f:\test\bar\test.ps1:
07 fd 41 59 6b fa 90 06 49 4f bf e3 dd be 0d 1c
MD5 hash of file f:\test\bar - Copy\test with space.cmd:
eb 4f 28 f4 a0 b0 c5 21 0d e8 5f 99 0f d8 fd ab
MD5 hash of file f:\test\bar - Copy\test.html:
3a 68 3a f6 4e 88 f1 22 62 d6 46 dc bb 54 59 45
MD5 hash of file f:\test\bar - Copy\test.ps1:
07 fd 41 59 6b fa 90 06 49 4f bf e3 dd be 0d 1c
MD5 hash of file f:\test\foo\test.sh:
d2 12 38 76 9d 8e 9f 51 1a 60 0b 15 6c 0c f8 38
MD5 hash of file f:\test\foo\test.xml:
cd 8f d1 c6 66 ac ff 7f 98 d2 e9 4a ad b5 20 1f
MD5 hash of file f:\test\foo\test.yaml:
78 ce a1 f0 97 46 ee 32 c6 7f f6 16 8d 94 04 d2
MD5 hash of file f:\test\foo\test.yml:
78 ce a1 f0 97 46 ee 32 c6 7f f6 16 8d 94 04 d2
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [CertUtil Certification Authority Utility - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html)
- [Dir - list files and folders - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [Findstr - Search for strings - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [For - Loop through files - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)
- [For - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

Comment: thanks! Now I only need to fugure out how to make it read files with space in it. like `C:\folder2\Some File.txt `

Comment: @user1889297 Fixed and answer updated.

Comment: @user1889297 Do you need more help? If this answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the accept button (the tick ✓ button).